# PyTorch does not install via conda on my Windows PC

Tags: windows, deep-learning, conda

When I type in my console:

`conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch`

to installing PyTorch, I get a `CondaHTTP` error. I already reinstalled conda unchanged the installation path, but nothing changed. I also tried to install it without CUDA, but it didn't help.

I get this output:

```
C:\Users\lennert>conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c
pytorch Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
<https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors
are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please
file a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
/pkgs/free/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t
connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

Is there another way to instal PyTorch? I read that I can install the offline package of conda but didn't figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

This error may be occuring due to firewall issue.

Try adding --insecure to command.

```
conda install --insecure pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch
```

If this doesn't work out then download the source file and then install on local system.