# CondaHTTPError while pytorch installation

Tags: http, pytorch, connection

I have installed Anaconda 4.2 on Windows 10. When I try to run the following command to install PyTorch.

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

I get the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\DELL>conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64'
```

Can anyone help me resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to run the command again, as suggested by the error message?

Comment: Yes....several times. But the same error persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyTorch does not install via conda on my Windows PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548414/pytorch-does-not-install-via-conda-on-my-windows-pc)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the --insecure flag like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548414/pytorch-does-not-install-via-conda-on-my-windows-pc) to disable ssl verification.