# Struggling to install PyTorch on windows 10 with anaconda 3.26.0 python 3.11.4

Tags: python, http, pytorch, anaconda

I have tried numerous ways to install PyTorch:

- !pip install torch --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/
- !pip cache purge
- !conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c
- pytorch !pip install torch

and i have had no luck!
i am new to this so im not sure if thi si s a simple fix but i alos tried opening anaconda prompt and using:

- (base) C:>conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch

However i got this error: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64/current_repodata.json
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https//conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64'

Lastly i tried this, and also got no where!

(base) C:>echo "$http_proxy"
"$http_proxy"

(base) C:>proxy_servers:
'proxy_servers:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Please help! if you could answer in the simplest way possible with steps for me to take that would be greatly appreciated! as i am still teaching myself so i may find it hard to understand!

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyTorch does not install via conda on my Windows PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548414/pytorch-does-not-install-via-conda-on-my-windows-pc)